# knockoutjs bind multiple input elements to one observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to bind two or more input elements to one observable property of the viewModel.

For example, I might have a property called Telephone number which consists of Area code and number. I would like to show two textboxes for user input and it would update single observable in the viewmodel (it may be stored as comma separated string or array). I don't want to have multiple property and then have a computed property for telephone number because I don't know how many textboxes will be displayed to user for input (generated dynamically using template).

Is it possible to achieve? Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the fiddle for better understanding http://jsfiddle.net/amitava82/wMH8J/2/

Answer (score 0):

If your data is combined into one observable, you need somethign to parse or split them out. One way is to use computeds. If you wanted 3 (just picking a number) textboxes for phone number and they all point to 1 phone number observable, you could create read/write computed properties for the parts and bind those to the input textboxes. For example, the area code textbox would be bound to a computed called areacode which reads the first 3 chars of the phone number. Its writeable aspect would simply write those 3 back to the phonenumber observable.

Comment: Yes I know this technique from KO documentation. But the problem is I don't know how many textboxes (or other input types) I'll need beforehand (three maximum so far). The idea is, I'll have a dropdown list with operators (IS, IN BETWEEN, ONE OF etc). On select, IS will give me  single textbox/select, where as IN BETWEEN renders two textboxes and ONE OF gives the user a multiselect list to choose (and so on). I want to capture any of these inputs into one Observable. I hope I got the idea across.

Comment: Perhaps create a fiddle to help demonstrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you don't want to use your view model to manage this, the next place is custom bindings. If you provide a clear and complete example of what you want to do, I could answer more specifically.

Comment: I've added a fiddle with original post. I'm new to KO and my approach might not be ideal. Please advice. Thanks!